# Google Admob banner Ad not display

Tags: android

I am developing one app. I want to show banner ad at the bottom of the screen.
Everything i did correctly. But i always getting error callback method `onAdloadFailed` method with `error code 0`.(`Failed to load ad: 0`)

Anyone please help me find out solution for that.

Thanks and Regards,
Gowtham.R

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816198/4336740

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admob ads not loading - Failed to load ad: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378002/admob-ads-not-loading-failed-to-load-ad-0)

Comment: There is no fault in your code. It's all good. You just need to wait a little. Your ad id is newly created so it will take some time to fetch ads from google servers. You can verify this by adding banner/interstitial ad id you creating for earlier applications and you'll see that they work.

Comment: But i  created adunitid yesterday itself.iOS app getting google ad.

Comment: i am getting test ad only.

Comment: AdMob Ad ids may take few hours to get approval. Just wait for few hours