# Failed to load AdMob on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, admob

Whenever I try to load an ad using AdMob, I get the following error

```
W/Ads     (23418): There was a problem getting an ad 
response.ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads     (23418): Failed to load ad: 0
W/flutter (23418): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
I/flutter (23418): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

I am using the android emulator and I am using only banner ads and I don't know why this error is occurring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378002/admob-ads-not-loading-failed-to-load-ad-0

Answer (score 16):

When I used **firebase_admob** 0.9.0+3, I encountered this error, this resolution worked for me, below:

You need to add **"admob_app_id**" value into **..android/app/google-services.json** file, after the "services" tag.

"admob_app_id": "ca-app-pub-your app~id" *(**change your admob app id here)*

You can find this file also **admob panel/ your app / your banner name / Implementation instructions / bullet nr. 3**

(if you already have this file, add only this line)

---

By the way, meaning the other fail numbers are :

- onAdFailedToLoad: 2 (The current network security does not allow the
  ad to arrive)
- onAdFailedToLoad: 3 (No problem in admob call, but
  admob repository did not send ads - generally in emulators)

The remaining fail numbers can be found [Here](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. BTW after "enabling" AdMob you can also just re-download the google-services.json file from Firebase Settings again.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this explanation first from community**
[Google community explanation of error codes](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en)

if still doesn't work, It could be because of unimplemented steps in the AdMob account. Example. **Payment verification** or **account verification**.

Go to your AdMob account home [Admob Home](https://apps.admob.com/v2/home) and check for these notifications
[image: Google FAQ]

Detailed info about error codes is given here

If everything[image: Account verified] in AdMob account is okay, It should show something like this in home page

Answer (score 0):

A problem like me.

**Let's see the solution to my problem.**

I used `admob_flutter 0.3.4`

https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Let's **see** how to **config**.

If this package you can **config** according to the document below,

https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter/example

**iOS**

File: **Info.plist** add below,

```
<key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
<true/>
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

**Android**

File: **AndroidManifest.xml** add code below,

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
    android:value="true"/>
```

**Run test:**

iOS:

[image]

Android

[image]

Finally,

In case anyone with problems like me will be saved time

**flutter doctor -v**

[image]

**Work for me. ^___^**