# google admob doesn't load native advertisement for real id

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I am trying to add native admob advertisement on my application, When I am testing with sample advertisement unit id for Native Advanced: **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110**, it works, I am getting advertisement on my application but When I try my real native advertisement id, it doesn't work it can't load advertisement,it shows blank screen, I published application to google play market and I wait 3 days but it doesn't load, I got below warning from advertisement. How can I solve this problem? Please help me, thanks..

```
I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> The ad request returned a no fill for the particular slot. The error log below that says 'Malformed native JSON response' is a benign warning that will be removed in a future SDK release.
I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> The ad request returned a no fill for the particular slot. The error log below that says 'Malformed native JSON response' is a benign warning that will be removed in a future SDK release.
I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> The ad request returned a no fill for the particular slot. The error log below that says 'Malformed native JSON response' is a benign warning that will be removed in a future SDK release.
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
```

Comment: The same question with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378002/admob-ads-not-loading-failed-to-load-ad-0
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378002/admob-ads-not-loading-failed-to-load-ad-0

Answer (score 0):

**The ad request returned a no fill for the particular slot**
->This indicates that there is no advertisements to be shown for your country/place.

try using ad Mediation to fix the fill rate
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediate