# AdMob Real Ads dont show

Tags: android, admob

My Ads donot show.

I am developing an app that requires Ads. Currently for testing, I have the app in the Internal Test Track of Google Play console for closed Testing. So, I cannot link it to an app in Play store in Admob.

So, to test them, all the while I have been Sample Test Ad Units, specifically Interstitial and Rewarded Video Ads. They load fine.

Today, I decided to switch to production Ads, as I wanted to release the App. So , I have created new Ad Units for both Rewarded and intersitial. Replaced the test Ad ID units with production Ad Unit IDs. I see "Ad failed to load : 0" .

Instead of using sample Ad Units, I tried making my device set Test Device. I see the follwing log

I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0

I am not sure what the issue is. I am still in the internal Test Track. Is the an issue? Do the production Ads work only when linked to an app in Google Play?

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Please see the attached image for Admob Ad units

The code is as show below:

Manifest.xml:

```
    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
         android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx" />
```

build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
```

Implementing AdMob :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //Rest of the code


   MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
         Log.w(TAG, " initialized mobile ad");
      }
   });

   List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
       RequestConfiguration configuration =
       new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
       MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);

   }

   public void loadInterstitialAd(){
   mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
   this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
   //mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


   mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAdLoaded() {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
     } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
     }
   }

  @Override
  public void onAdClosed() {
     Log.w(TAG, "Interstitial ad cloed ");
     onInterstitialshowed();
  }
    });
  }


  public void loadRewardedAd(){
   this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
  //this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
  RewardedAdLoadCallback callback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback(){
  @Override
  public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
     super.onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(i);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
     super.onRewardedAdLoaded();
     showRewardedAd();
  }
  };
  this.rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), callback);
  }

     public void showRewardedAd(){
     if(rewardedAd.isLoaded()){
     RewardedAdCallback callback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onUserEarnedReward");
     }

     @Override
     public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
        super.onRewardedAdOpened();
        Log.w(TAG, "OnRewardAdOpened");
     }

     @Override
     public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
        super.onRewardedAdClosed();
        onRewardedAdLoadedOnClick();
     }

     @Override
     public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int i) {
        super.onRewardedAdFailedToShow(i);
        Log.w(TAG, "onRewardedAdFailedToShow");
     }
  };
  this.rewardedAd.show(this, callback);
  }else{
  Log.i(TAG, "Ad not loaded");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38378002/11105280

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with SDK ANDROID LEVEL 30. When I changed it to SDK ANDROID LEVEL 29 the ADS showed.